# Firebase.set fails. Async Not On Place

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok guys so i have this code and it tells me Firebase.set(); failed(Minimalisic code):

```
 $scope.$evalAsync(
                              function() {
                                        var letterAvatar = letterAvatarService.getLetterURL($scope.register.username);
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                            refService.ref().child("UserAuthInfo").child(userData.uid).set({
                                                Username: $scope.register.username,
                                                Email: $scope.register.email,
                                                UID: userData.uid,
                                                Image: letterAvatarService.getLetterURL($scope.register.username),
                                                Moderator: false,
                                                BronzeBadge: 0,
                                                SilverBadge: 0,
                                                GoldBadge: 0,
                                                PlatinumBadge: 0,
                                                newUser: true,
                                                profileBackground: 'http://rmdeaftheatre.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/gray-background-3.jpg',
                                                followers: 0,
                                                following: 0,
                                                profileViews: 0,
                                                Precence: -1,
                                            });

                                        }, 1500)

                                        alertify.success("Sucessfully Registered")
                                    }
                                );
```

As you can see i put $evalAsync there but these appears(for visuals):

[image]

Here is my Code For the service(Full):

```
(function(angular){

    var app = angular.module('ForumApp')

    app.service('letterAvatarService', ['$http',letterAvatarServiceFunc])

    function letterAvatarServiceFunc($http){




        this.getLetterURL = function(string){
            $http.get('services/assets/json/letterJSON.json').then(function(value) {
                this.letters = value.status;
                  var char = string.charAt(0);
                    var len = 0;
                    var lenNum = 0;
                    var URLVALUE = '';

                    for(var i in value.data.letters){
                        len++;
                        if(i == (char.toLowerCase())){
                            URLVALUE = value.data.letters[i].URL;
                        }
                    }

                    for(var i in value.data.numbers){
                        lenNum++;
                        if(i == (char)){
                            URLVALUE = value.data.numbers[i].URL;
                        }
                    }

                    if(!URLVALUE){
                        URLVALUE = value.data.Mystery
                    }

                    console.log(URLVALUE);
            });




        }    

    }
})(angular);
```

Please Help.

Comment: How did it fail? Is there an error message?

Comment: The error message is Firebase.set(); failed.. you can see my image above to see it more clearly.. To fix this, i just said *** it, and copied the whole jason to this.letters in the service and stop using $http ...